# How to export an underscore in org-mode, using markdown or gfm, without producing a backslash escaped underscore `\_`?

Tags: org-mode, markdown

Given a file:

```
#+OPTIONS: ^:nil
* heading
  this is some text_to_export
```

`C-c C-e m m` or `M-x org-md-export-as-markdown` yields:

```
# heading

this is some text\_to\_export
```

HTML export does not add the backslashes and produces the intended `text_to_export`.

How do I avoid turning `_` into `\_` in markdown export?

Comment: apparently `\under{}` works, based on https://stackoverflow.com/a/31207996/222519, though it seems like there should be another method based on the inconsistency between html and md export.

Comment: According to the [Markdown syntax page](https://daringfireball.net/projects/markdown/syntax#em), `text_to_export` will italicize  the `to` (it will actually wrap in HTML `<em>` markup when exported to HTML). I presume that's why the Org mode md exporter does the escaping.

Comment: I usually wrap the `text_to_export` with verbatim syntax `=text_to_export=` to prevent formatting in markdown.

Comment: ahh... I oversimplified my question into asking the wrong thing, I was actually trying to get :white_check_mark: to render as emoji in gitlab using gitlab's org rendering, and was thinking the key was avoiding the `\_`. I'd forgotten about italics, and ... really this is the wrong question for that task which is ultimately a gitlab issue. I ended up switching to markdown export in emacs rather than letting gitlab render the .org file directly.